# Append datasets from xlsx and databse - Talend

Tags: talend

I have three Excel files and one database connection which I need to append as a part of my flow. All four datasets in the pre-append stage have just one column.
[image]

When I try to use tUnite, I get the error for tFileInputExcel - see the screenshot. Moreover, I cannot join the database connection with tUnite.

[image]

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the problem is with the tFileExist components (I think that's what these are on the left with the "if" links coming out) because each of them is trying to start a new flow.  Once you're joining them with the unite, there can be only one start to the flow - and this goes to the start of the first branch of the merge order.

You can move the if logic elsewhere.  Another idea is to put the output from each of the Excel into a tHashOutput (linked together), then use a tHashInput to write to your DB.

Comment: Yes, it looks like. For now, I append all tgree outcomes as a csv file and then, I have a stand-alone job where I read that 'working file' and do further processing. Strangely, I still could not use tunite when connecting csv and a database, so I had to append the database output to the working file- when reading the documentation, I got the impression that tunite to be used to append different data sources with the same schema.

Comment: You're right, tUnite will append different sources with the same data.  If you delete all of the tFileExist at the beginning, or move them elsewhere, your tUnite will work.  It just doesn't know where to start.